# Upload file to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there are lot of threads like this, I tried like 100 examples, all of them throw the same exception:

> The specified bucket is not valid.

I contacted the s3 admin, he said, everything is correct from his side, and he said, he set full permissions, no deny statements, so we can test,
but my app still throws the same exception, here is the code..

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

namespace AmazonS3
{
    public class FileUploader
    {
        private const string S3_Bucket_ARN = "(hidden)";
        private const string IAM_User_ARN = "(hidden)";
        private const string Access_Key_ID = "(hidden)";
        private const string Secret_access_Key = "(hidden)";

        public void UploadFile(string Filepath)
        {
            Program.WriteLine(MessageStatus.Neutral, "[1/4] Connecting to Amazon S3 . . .");
            using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(Access_Key_ID, Secret_access_Key, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                Program.WriteLine(MessageStatus.Neutral, "[2/4] Preparing upload request . . .");
                var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    FilePath = Filepath,
                    BucketName = S3_Bucket_ARN,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };

                Program.WriteLine(MessageStatus.Neutral, $"[3/4] Uploading file: \"{Filepath}\" . . .");
                var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);

                Program.WriteLine(MessageStatus.Neutral, $"[4/4] File: \"{Filepath}\" successfully uploaded.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the hidden strings are ofcourse replaced by my real credentials, I just edited them now.
Anyway what seems incorrect here? Im stuck for days now, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all 100 examples throw the same error, perhaps your bucket is invalid? Are you absolutely sure you have used the correct details?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I tought the first time, but the s3 admin sent me those credentials, even after that, we checked again, the credentials are correct :/

Comment: perhaps you have a typo in the bucket name

Comment: There is something wrong with your bucket name.

Comment: better create a new bucket and try :)

Comment: There maybe the issue with the permission of bucket. You need to give AllowPublicRead permission.

Comment: Are you sure that the bucket is in us-east-1 (N. Virginia)?

Comment: Actually i dont know where the bucket is, i only know its somewhere in america, im in europe.

Comment: I'd be willing to wager that the problem is `BucketName = S3_Bucket_ARN`... `BucketName` expects a *bucket name*, not an ARN.  Using a value here that looks like `arn:aws:s3:...` would definitely be invalid.

Comment: yeah i use a value that looks like arn:aws:s3:... as bucket name, i will contact the admin right now to ask for the correct name.

Comment: Okay, problem solved, the problem was definitely in the bucket name,
it should not start with arn:aws:s3.... just like @Michael-sqlbot said, thank you, and thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
BucketName = S3_Bucket_ARN
```

ARNs are [Amazon Resource Names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html), which are a namespace for uniquely identifying Amazon resources... but in this case, `BucketName` is expecting only the actual name of the bucket, e.g. `my-example-bucket`.

If you are using the bucket ARN, you are passing a value that looks like `arn:aws:s3:::my-example-bucket`, which is not only not the bucket name, but also contains characters (`:`) that aren't valid in bucket names.

The [S3 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) indicates that there are two different errors possible when a bucket name isn't right:

```
InvalidBucketName | The specified bucket is not valid.
NoSuchBucket      | The specified bucket does not exist.
```

The first one means the bucket name contains invalid characters.

Answer (score 2):

I have used below method recently it may help

```
        private string UploadAWS(Stream stream, string contentType, string name,string orgfileName,string lable)
    {
        string accessKey = "xxxxx";
        string secretKey = "xxxxxxx";

        using (client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            return WritingAnObject(stream, contentType, name, orgfileName,lable);
        }
    }

    private string WritingAnObject(Stream stream, string contentType, string name,string orgfileName,string lable)
    {
        string rtn = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            string bucketName = "xxxxxxxx";

            PutObjectRequest putRequest2 = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = name,
                ContentType = contentType,
                InputStream = stream
            };
            putRequest2.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", lable);
            putRequest2.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-original-file-name", orgfileName);

            PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(putRequest2);

        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                ||
                amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                rtn="Check the provided AWS Credentials.";
            }
            else
            {
                rtn="Error occurred. Message:"+ amazonS3Exception.Message + " when writing an object";
            }
        }

        return rtn;

    }
```

Comment: Again throws the same exception :/ But thanks for helping